# How can I use multiple NICs on Windows Server 2008 function as a switch

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, switch

I have a win2008 Server with 4 network ports (A,B,C and D) where only 1 port A is connected to the LAN (192.168.0.0/24). The other 3 ports (B,C and D) are not in use.

I have another PC want to join the same LAN(192.168.0.0/24) by connecting the pc's network port P to one of those 3 unused network ports (I am using network port B in this case) on win2008 server. The PC network connection is set to DHCP.

I read about "network bridging", "network card teaming(for win2012)" and "Internet Sharing" but none of those works:

- Bridging: I tried to bridge the network port A and B but the "bridged network" says "unidentified network" and I stuck there.
- Teaming: For win2012 ONLY, I am using Win2008 R2.
- Internet Sharing: The PC network works but the IP (192.168.137.100) is not in the same network as the server (192.168.0.0/24).

How to get my PC to join the server's IP network (192.168.0.0/24)? That is to say my Win2008 server acts as a switch. Linux can do it easily but I can ONLY use windows 2008 R2.